# Poor performance with custom geometry

Tags: three.js

I am trying to create a model consisting of lot of interconnected cubes. I am using the THREE.Geometry to define the vertices and the faces. In the code below if the totalcubes is set to a high number (~2000), the FPS drops to single digits. This seems strange as I have seen more complicated meshes created three.js.

In the code below, a parent mesh object is created first and added to the scene. Following that a for-loop generates the mesh for the cubes and adds it to the parent object.

The variable totalcubes=2000 defines the number of cubes to draw. If set to a small value, say 10 the rotation is smooth, however a value of 2000 isnt.
How can the following code be improved?

```
<html>

<head>
    <title>Display Mesh</title>

    <script src="https://rawgit.com/mrdoob/stats.js/master/build/stats.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/threejs/r84/three.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://threejs.org/examples/js/controls/OrbitControls.js"></script>
    <style>
        body {
            /* set margin to 0 and overflow to hidden, to go fullscreen */
            margin: 0;
            overflow: hidden;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>

    <!-- Div which will hold the Output -->
    <div id="WebGL-output">
    </div>


    <script>
    //Change total number of cubes to be drawn
totalcubes=2000;

function init() {


    // create a scene, that will hold all our elements such as objects, cameras and lights.
    var scene = new THREE.Scene();

    // create a camera, which defines where we're looking at.
    var camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(45, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight,0.1,10000);

    // create a render and set the size
    var renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
    renderer.setClearColor();
    renderer.setClearColor(new THREE.Color(0xEEEEEE));
    renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);

    // show axes in the screen
    var axes = new THREE.AxisHelper(20);
    scene.add(axes);

    // create parent mesh to which we add all child geometries
    var geom = new THREE.Geometry();
    var materials = [
    new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial({opacity: 0.6, color: 0x44ff44, transparent: true}),
    new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({color: 0x000000, wireframe: true})
    ];

    var mesh = THREE.SceneUtils.createMultiMaterialObject(geom, materials);
    scene.add(mesh);

    //define face order for our cubes
    var faces = [
        new THREE.Face3(2, 1, 0), 
        new THREE.Face3(0, 3, 2), 

        new THREE.Face3(5, 4,7), 
        new THREE.Face3(7, 6, 5),

        new THREE.Face3(1, 5, 4), 
        new THREE.Face3(4, 0, 1), 

        new THREE.Face3(1, 2, 6), 
        new THREE.Face3(6, 5, 1), 

        new THREE.Face3(3, 7, 6), 
        new THREE.Face3(6, 2, 3), 

        new THREE.Face3(7, 3, 0), 
        new THREE.Face3(0, 4, 7), 
        ];

    //define co-ordinates of the first cube. This acts a template for all other cubes
    var vertices = [
    new THREE.Vector3(-5.,           5.,          10.), 
    new THREE.Vector3(-5.,          -5.,          10.), 
    new THREE.Vector3(-5.,          -5.,           0.), 
    new THREE.Vector3(-5.,           5.,           0.), 
    new THREE.Vector3(5.,           5.,          10.), 
    new THREE.Vector3(5.,          -5.,          10.), 
    new THREE.Vector3( 5.,          -5.,           0.),
    new THREE.Vector3(5.,           5.,           0.) 
        ];

//This loop generates the vertices for the cubes, creates mesh object for each cube and adds to the parent object
for (cube=0; cube<totalcubes;cube++)
{

    var vertices1 = [
    new THREE.Vector3(vertices[2].x,          vertices[2].y,         vertices[2].z-10*cube),
    new THREE.Vector3(vertices[3].x,          vertices[3].y,         vertices[3].z-10*cube),
    new THREE.Vector3(vertices[3].x,          vertices[3].y,         vertices[3].z),
    new THREE.Vector3(vertices[2].x,          vertices[2].y,         vertices[2].z),
    new THREE.Vector3(vertices[6].x,          vertices[6].y,         vertices[6].z-10*cube),
    new THREE.Vector3(vertices[7].x,          vertices[7].y,         vertices[7].z-10*cube),
    new THREE.Vector3(vertices[7].x,          vertices[7].y,         vertices[7].z),
    new THREE.Vector3(vertices[6].x,          vertices[6].y,         vertices[6].z)
    ]

    var geom1 = new THREE.Geometry();
    geom1.vertices = vertices1;
    geom1.faces = faces;

    geom1.name=cube;
    var mesh1 = THREE.SceneUtils.createMultiMaterialObject(geom1, materials);
    mesh.add(mesh1);
}


    // position and point the camera to the center of the scene
    camera.position.x = 30;
    camera.position.y = 40;
    camera.position.z = 50;
    camera.lookAt(scene.position);
    controls = new THREE.OrbitControls( camera, renderer.domElement );
    controls.addEventListener( 'change', render ); // remove when using animation loop

    stats = new Stats();
    stats.showPanel( 0 ); // 0: fps, 1: ms, 2: mb, 3+: custom
    document.body.appendChild(stats.dom);

    // add the output of the renderer to the html element
    document.getElementById("WebGL-output").appendChild(renderer.domElement);

    function render() {
            renderer.render(scene, camera);
            requestAnimationFrame(render);
             stats.update();
         }
    render();
}


window.onload = init;
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

==========================================

Based on responses below, the code is re-written to create a single geometry and use it with different meshes. Does the code below reflect your suggestions?

Rotation is smoother now. Pushing this further I get about 16 FPS for totalcubes=20,000. My geometry will contain more than 50,000 cubes. Should i display only 2000 at a time?

```
    // create parent mesh to which we add all child meshes
    var geom = new THREE.Geometry();

//define face order for our cubes
    var faces = [
        new THREE.Face3(2, 1, 0), 
        new THREE.Face3(0, 3, 2), 

        new THREE.Face3(5, 4,7), 
        new THREE.Face3(7, 6, 5), 

        new THREE.Face3(1, 5, 4), 
        new THREE.Face3(4, 0, 1), 

        new THREE.Face3(1, 2, 6), 
        new THREE.Face3(6, 5, 1), 

        new THREE.Face3(3, 7, 6), 
        new THREE.Face3(6, 2, 3), 

        new THREE.Face3(7, 3, 0), 
        new THREE.Face3(0, 4, 7), 
        ];
 //define co-ordinates of the first cube. This acts a template for all other cubes
    var vertices = [
    new THREE.Vector3(-5.,           5.,          10.), 
    new THREE.Vector3(-5.,          -5.,          10.), 
    new THREE.Vector3(-5.,          -5.,           0.), 
    new THREE.Vector3(-5.,           5.,           0.), 
    new THREE.Vector3(5.,           5.,          10.), 
    new THREE.Vector3(5.,          -5.,          10.), 
    new THREE.Vector3( 5.,          -5.,           0.),
    new THREE.Vector3(5.,           5.,           0.) 
        ];

    geom.vertices = vertices;
    geom.faces = faces;


    var materials = [
    new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial({opacity: 0.6, color: 0x44ff44, transparent: true}),
    new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({color: 0x000000, wireframe: true})
    ];

    var mesh = THREE.SceneUtils.createMultiMaterialObject(geom, materials);
    scene.add(mesh);    


//This loop generates the position of the cubes. The scaling factor is 1 as all cubes are assumed to be same size.
for (cube=0; cube<totalcubes;cube++)
{
    var mesh1 = THREE.SceneUtils.createMultiMaterialObject(geom, materials);
    mesh.add(mesh1);
    mesh1.scale.set(1,1,1);
    mesh1.position.set(0,0,-10*cube);  
}
```

Comment: Not entirely sure what SceneUtils does, need to look into it.

Answer (score 0):

1. don't create `totalcubes` different geometries, this change carries overhead. Instead create one cubeGeometry and instantiate `totalcubes` different meshes with the **same** geometry.
2. in order to reduce the overhead from issuing `totalcubes` drawcalls, you can batch them using `THREE.InstancedBufferGeometry` or something like [this](https://www.npmjs.com/package/three-instanced-mesh)

Comment: I am not sure on how to implement your first suggestion. Each cube is of a different size, so the geometry has to be different each time. So, I dont understand how can i have the same geometry with a different mesh.

Comment: You can create one `Geometry` and share it among all of your `Mesh` objects, which can have different `scale` values.

Comment: what @TheJim01 said :)

Comment: The solutions works well if the shape of all the quadrilaterals is the same. So simply scaling in x, y and z would work. However, the method fails if these brick shaped elements have varying corner angles. Then simply scaling will not work. Any idea what could then be done?

Comment: Each and every one has a different corner angle? In that case, optimizing it would require some GLSL work. You can for example, merge all the varying cubes into one geometry, but give each cube a different attribute id. Then use some logic to animate them if they need to be animated.

Comment: The hexahderal geometry is produced from a CAD software. Hence each of them may have a slightly different corner angle. If we combine the cubes into 1 geometry, arent we back to square one, i.e. each cube will need to be rendered individually.  If there was a way to define the cube using corner angles, and scale the mesh corner angles the first idea proposed would work.

Comment: **1)** Your post says you wanted cubes, so you got an answer for cubes. Don't ask for a pentagon when you really want a star. **2)** As @pailhead suggested, this kind of thing would probably be easier in a vertex shader. You'll still start with a "unit hexahedron", and give it attributes to group vertices into corners, and uniforms for describing corner angles and side scaling.

Comment: You asked about what is causing performance issues, and this should be the right answer.